# Problem mounting local directory to container in docker (docker volumes).

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have three files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    hello-world:
        build: .
        volumes:
         - ./src:/var/www/html
        ports:
         - 80:80
```

src/index.php:

```
<?php

echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

I then run the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

And up until this point everything's fine, but when I access localhost in my browser I get:

403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

...and from the container the error message:

Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

However, if I from the docker-compose.yml file remove the 2 lines:

```
        volumes:
         - ./src:/var/www/html
```

...everything works fine (except the folder is not mounted). What am I doing wrong? It obviously doesn't like me mounting the volume, causing the directory /var/www/html/ to be empty, but why?

Comment: Where have you installed docker (Linux, Windows, Mac)? If the latter two, what is the path on your host? Have you exec'd into the container and verified the directory is empty, or just a permission denied?

Answer (score 2):

In your build file you are copying the contents of src into the image (under `/var/www/html`). The src directory is part of the build context, and must be below the 'build' root directory. This is probably where you ran the docker build command from, and is usually the place the `dockerfile` lives.

In your compose file you are mapping the `src` directory over the top of `/var/www/html`, replacing its contents with `src` at runtime.

I'm guessing that you only actually want to do one of these two things. Either is fine, depending on what you're trying to achieve, but based on your report it looks like the place you're running your `docker-compose up` from has an empty `src` directory, hence the error message. To fix this, either use an absolute path to the directory you want to serve or remove the `volumes` definition for that container.

One way to check this (assuming you tagged your image `HelloWorld`):

```
docker run -it -d --name helloworld -p 80:80 HelloWorld
```

Then, `docker ps` just to check that it's running. If everything is ok, try this:

```
docker exec -it -w /var/www/html helloworld ls -gAlFh
```

This should give you a list of what's in that directory. You can also try this:

```
docker exec -it -w /var/www/html helloworld sh
```

To get a shell in that directory so that you can explore more easily.

Comment: Yes, this works I can see the index.php inside the /var/www/html folder and I can access the page in the browser. That's not the problem. I want to mount a volume so that I won't have to rebuild the image whenever I modify the php file, and I seem to be unable to.